# In IntelliJ IDEA, how can I hide the bar in the left of the text editor?

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA there is a vertical bar in the left of the text editor, which makes it possible to add and remove breakpoints and see some other stuff that I never use. I would like to get rid of it in order to have a less cluttered IDE. Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot turn the gutter off completely. You can disable the showing of small icon previews and CSS colors:

- Settings > [IDE Settings] > Editor > Appearance

  - Show icon preview in gutter for small icons (Java)
  - Show CSS color preview icon in gutter

You can also turn of line numbers by right clicking the gutter.

Other than that, it is considered an integral part of the IDE.

Comment: Ah.. It's quite not integral for me and my Javascript or Elm code. And it's just taking space there..